# Using pg_dump when connecting via a service

Tags: postgresql, pg-dump

I connect to my postgres server using `psql "service=subscription"`. How do I use the service with `pg_dump`?

I tried to do the following:
`pg_dump -h "service=subscription" > /home/fogest/dump.out`

This however did not work.

How should I be doing this?

Edit: The error when I do the following:

```
pg_dump -h "service=subscription" odyssey_prod > /u3/jhvisser/dump.out
pg_dump: [archiver (db)] connection to database "odyssey_prod" failed: could not translate host name "service=subscription" to address: Name or service not known
```

Comment: "Did not work". What, exactly, did not work - what happened or did not happen? Do you have a `~/.pg_service.conf` file?

Comment: @CraigRinger Yes I have a `pg_service` file. I updated the original post with details.

Comment: PostgreSQL version and OS?

Comment: What happens when you use connection options with `pg_dump` the same way you used them with `psql`, e.g. `pg_dump "service=subscription" ...` ?

Comment: @CraigRinger I currently can't check, but it should be running the latest version and on Ubuntu 12.04. I can check the version later if needed.

Comment: @MilenA.Radev It returns an error stating I have too many parameters. It seems to treat the `"service=subscription"` part as the database name.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can't use `-h` to specify a connection-string. It can only be an actual hostname or IP.

To connect to a service (or use any other connection string) just pass it as a non-switch argument:

```
pg_dump "service=subscription"
```

or (I know this is counter-intuitive) pass it as *the database name*:

```
pg_dump -d "service=subscription"
```

This works with any `libpq` client (`psql`, `pg_restore`, etc).

Comment: Okay, but does this work with `pg_dump`?

Comment: Yes; any libpq client.